How to get the path to the folder of a python script that is chunkwise executed in DataSpell?
I am working on a Python script using JetBrain's DataSpell 2024.2. The script should be able to find the path to the directory it is in and output that path as a string. This should work both when I run the entire code in one go by pressing "Run All" in the menu bar, and also - and this seems to be the tricky part - when I run the code in the editor chunk by chunk by repeatedly pressing "Run Cell and Select Below".
Solutions with __file__ do not work as I get the error NameError: name '__file__' is not defined. Did you mean: '__name__'?. I also tried several approaches using os.getcwd() but they return some higher-level parent directory. (As an aside, this approach worked before updating DataSpell to the current version.) Last, inspect.getfile() or inspect.getsourcefile() resulted in strings of the form '<ipython-input-8-525ac49598a2>'.
Is there a solution to my problem at all, and if so, what is it? Thanks a lot for any ideas!
